# regex: output the whole word having even number of a specific letter

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I would like to get words having even number(excluding 0) of letter A in a string. For example, I have a string "aa abs aadfc asdacx adds asdwe", then the output should be ['aa', 'aadfc', 'asdacx'] using re.findall.

I write the regex in this way: `pattern = r'\b[^A]*[(A[^A]*A[^A]*)+]\b'`. However, the output is very strange. For example, `re.findall(pattern, 'eeee')` only return 'ee'. I guess the problem is from the parenthesis, any one can help me out?

Comment: why would you use regex for this? im pretty sure there are easier ways to accomplish this

Comment: @Joran Beasley To practice regex.... I know there are easier way too haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex for this job:

```bash
\b(?:(?:[^a\W]*a){2})+[^a\W]*\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QfGYv6/3)

[**<kbd>Online Code Demo</kbd>**](https://ideone.com/VJ6tXD)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group 1

  - `(?:`: Start non-capture group 2

    - `[^a\W]*`: Match 0 or more of any char that is not `a` and not a not-word
    - `a`: Match `a`
  - `){2}`: End non-capture group 2. Repeat this group exactly 2 times
- `)+`: End non-capture group 1. Repeat this group 1+ times
- `[^a\W]*`: Match 0 or more of any char that is not `a` and not a not-word
- `\b`: Word boundary

**Code:**

```py
import re
 
s = "aa abs aadfc asdacx adds asdwe bcadcapca"
 
print (re.findall(r'\b(?:(?:[^a\W]*a){2})+[^a\W]*\b', s))
```

**Output:**

```
['aa', 'aadfc', 'asdacx']
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply! Could you explain why you do not add ```\b``` at the end?

Comment: And I follow your idea to modify my idea, which is ```r'\b[^A]*(?:A[^A]*A[^A]*)+\b' ```but it still not work, the ```+``` sign do not effect. Do you know the reason? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry ending `\b` shud have been there, added and updated my answer. I have also added an online code demo and code sample in my answer.